# Why No Merkle tree in Hyperledger Fabric to track the world state

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I note that the previous Hyperledger Fabric v0.6 employs a **Merkle Bucket Tree** to organize the world states. And the merkle tree root hash is included in the block header, as a part of the consensus agreement.
In a similar fashion, Ethereum/Quorum and Hyperledger Sawtooth adopt Merkle tree variants in their data model to protect the world state.

But why does Hyperledger Fabric, from v1 onwards, abandon this Merkle-based data model? What is their design rationale? Is it due to efficiency or other factors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from Fabric 1.0, the validity of the transaction is determined in the peers, after the block was assembled.

Peers check things like endorsement policy and Multi-Version Concurrency Control conflicts, and a transaction might be deemed invalid, which means its state updates will not be applied.

At the time of generating the block in the ordering service, the validity of the transaction is unknown yet, and the orderers have no idea about the world state (unlike the peers).

Comment: Since peers are responsible to perform the checking, is it true that clients trust the honest behavior of peers and their returned result in query for the world state?

Comment: Yes it is true, but you can always ask several peers and compare